# Android SurfaceView: textsize changing in Paint is not smooth

Tags: android, canvas, text, surfaceview, paint

I have a problem with drawing text on canvas of `SurfaceView`. I need to draw text each frame with different size. To change text size i use:

```
    mTextPaint.setTextSize(mTextSize);
```

`mTextSize` is calculating correctly and has float values, but it looks like text
scaling is happening by steps and it is not smooth (looks like symbols are changing size, for example, from 9 to 10 like this 9  -> 9.25 -> 9.5 ->9.75 -> 10).
I used flags on paint but it didn't help.

```
    TextPaint mTextPaint = new TextPaint(TextPaint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | TextPaint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG | TextPaint.FAKE_BOLD_TEXT_FLAG | TextPaint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG);
    mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
```

Do font symbols have some predefined sizes or problem is in something other?